# Parsing HEX '0x0976b8' to color android

Tags: android

I tried below but it throws an saying error during parsing the color. Thanks in advance.

```
hexColorStr = "0x0976b8"
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(String.format("#%06X", Integer.parseInt(hexColorStr)))
```

**UPDATE:**
For some reason removing 0x in `"0x0976b8"` worked for me.

```
view.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("0x0976b8".replace("0x","#")));
```

Is there any reason why i have to remove 0x form `"0x0976b8"` to make it work. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(hexColorStr))
```

your string is hexadcimal format it will return

```
int color = 0xFFFF0000;
```

If you provide 6 hex digits, that means `RGB` (2 hex digits for each value of red, green and blue).

If you provide 8 hex digits, it's an `ARGB` (2 hex digits for each value of alpha, red, green and blue respectively).

see the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color)

Answer (score 1):

Parse color expects a certain format: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB.

Change to
`view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0976b8"));`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0976b8"));
```

Comment: it throws `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x0976b8"`

Comment: Sorry remove 0x it takes RRRGGBB or ARRGGBB